# Find a double digit (non/consecutive) in a number

Tags: regex, duplicates, digits

I am trying to write a regex expression to find double digits in a number.

I have r'(\d)\1+?' which works for 110 or 011, but not 101. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you meant `(\d)\d*\1`

Comment: please add examples in this question so that we can test RE

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, yes - it worked!!! You are a genius. Thank you for such an elegant answer! Could you just explain the syntax for others to understand?
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern `(\d)\1+?` you are capturing a single digit, and the backreference `\1` that refers to the exact same value as captured in group 1 is directly placed after the capture group.

This way, the backreference can not match the same value, if there are other (not the same digits) in between.

Note that if you just want a match, you can omit `+?` as that would repeat the backreference 1 or more times non greedy.

What you might do, is match optional digits using `\d*` in between.

```
(\d)\d*\1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LUIadt/1)